# Можно ли изменить код, чтобы он работал в классе "fragment"

Tags: java, android, массивы, изображения, случайные-числа

Это полностью рабочий код. Но, мне нужно,чтобы он работал не в полном классе, а в классе "fragment". Только у меня ничего не получается... Помогите пожалуйста. Задача такая: 4 картинки, рандомно меняются, при нажатии "button". Картинки берутся из библиотеки "array.preview" в отдельно файле.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;

public class Facts extends Activity {

    ImageView icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        icon1 = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.icon1);
        icon2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon2);
        icon3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon3);
        icon4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon4);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button );

        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getRandomImage();

                icon1.setImageResource(getRandomImage());
                icon2.setImageResource(getRandomImage());
                icon3.setImageResource(getRandomImage());
                icon4.setImageResource(getRandomImage());
            }});}

    private int getRandomImage() {
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.preview);
        int id = imgs.getResourceId(new Random().nextInt(imgs.length()), -1);
        imgs.recycle();
        return id;
    }
}
```

Если его перенести в файл "fragment" то получается ошибка, (setContentView) и (findViewById)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените

> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

на

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        @NotNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable final ViewGroup container,
        @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState
)
```

> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

на

```
 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
```

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

на

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_insurance_case_create, container, false);
```

> findViewById

на

```
view.findViewById
```

и верните из `onCreateView` метода `view`

```
return view;
```